# Why are Pycharm and VS Code giving me different results for printing with carriage return?

Tags: python-3.x, printing, carriage-return, python-3.9

I am trying to run the following code in both Pycharm and VS Code.

```
for x in range(10000, 0, -1):
  print(x, end='\r')
print()
```

In Pycharm, I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0LaFg.png) result.

However, in VS Code I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ym0db.png) result.
Carriage return is behaving differently in both.

Can someone explain why?

Comment: you are using an extra `print` in yr second result..that makes all the difference .

Comment: Thats not really what I was getting at. If you have the empty print statement in both, Pycharm returns 1 and VS Code returns 10000. Why is that?

Comment: i am getting the same output for both ide's...are u sure u have selected the right interpreter ?

Comment: Can you show your output? and what is your output?

Comment: I have selected the same interpreter for both

Comment: both Pycharm and VS code returns 10000 at my end.

Answer (score 1):

This is a quirk of each console's implementation. PyCharm, or at least your version, is probably clearing out the entire line when the `\r` is printed, while VSCode (and every other console I have tested, to include PowerShell and Cygwin) only sets the insertion point at the beginning.

The reason we see `10000` in these other consoles is because the last number printed before each time the number has one fewer digit is `10...0`. For example:

- At `x == 10000`, print 10000 and sets cursor back to beginning of line.
- Print `9999`, not overwriting the `0` at the end, leaving `99990`
- Then `99980`, then `99970`, etc.
- ...
- At `x == 1000`, the current output is `10010`. After printing, the output is once again `10000`.
- Then `99900`, `99800`, etc.
- ...
- At `x == 1`, the current output is `20000`. After printing, the output is `10000` again. This is the last number printed, so you see `10000`.

If you want to overwrite the whole number, one solution would be just to overwrite it with spaces, like so:

```
for x in range(10000, 0, -1):
    print(x, end='    \r')
print()
```

---

PS: For something completely different, a lot of online program runners will just treat the `\r` as a line break (e.g. TIO and Ideone), printing all the numbers.

Answer (score -1):

If you do it this way I think it will be solved:

```
for x in range(10000, 0, -1):

  print(x, end='\n')
```

Comment: No man, This negates the point. The idea is to use carriage return to replace the previous line.

Comment: The question was why both programs are giving different output results.